# How to config environment before running automated tests?

Tags: unit-testing, automation, nunit, automated-tests, nunit-3.0

I need a good practice to deal with my issue.

**The issue is:** I need to run automatic tests against a site. The site has different configurations that completely change its design (on some pages). For example I can config 2 different pages of login. And I need to test them both.

**First of all** I must make sure that a correct test is run against a correct configuration. So before each test I need to change site's config. It is not good if I have a thousand of test.

**So a solution that comes to my mind is** to not reconfigure the site each time but do it once and run all the tests that are corresponding to this configuration. But this solution doesn't seems to me as an easy one to make.

**For now what I did is:** I created a method that is run once before all the other tests and in this method I configure the site to make config that are used in the majority of the tests. All the other tests for now change the config before execution and after execution they change it back. It's not good at all.

**To do so I used NUnit3 SetUpFixture and OneTimeSetUp attributes:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs once before all the test in order to config the environment 
    /// </summary>
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class ConfigTests
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            try
            {
                //Here I config the stie
                CommonActions actions = new CommonActions(driver);
                actions.SwitchOffCombinedPaymentPage();
                driver.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

**What I thought after this is** that I'll be able to send parameters to SetUpFixture but first of all it's impossible and second of all it won't resolve the problem as this feature will just be run twice and the tests will be run against the last configuration.

**So guys, how to deal with a site testing that has a lot of configurations?**

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a test run parameter from the command-line (or in the .runsettings file if you are using the VS adapter) Your SetUpFixture can grab that parameter and do the initialization and any individual fixtures that need it can grab it as well.

See the --params option to nunit3-console and the TestContext.TestParameters property for accessing the values.

This answers your "first of all it's impossible" part. I didn't answer "second of all... " because I don't understand it. I'll add more if you can clarify.